# Dimplex SCx175l Water Cylinder - T&P valve leaking

Tags: leak, temperature, pressure

[Here is a video of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiCXR.jpg)

I've just moved into a flat and after hand-washing some dishes this water cylinder (Dimplex SCx175l) began 'draining' very loudly -- I let it go for about 30 minutes before turning off the main water shut off valve.

I am assuming this is a problem with the T&P valve so I'm wondering if it is safe to turn the water back on or if I should call out a professional to solve the issue.

Thanks,
Jack

Comment: You have only furnished the model name of an equipment/device that could be unfamiliar to most of the people here. Please indicate what type of equipment/device caused the problem, also the T&P valve.

Comment: @r13 I think you're imagining I know more than I do - everything in my post is 100% of the knowledge I have of the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the T & P valve in a gas water heater , no big deal just a good wrench. Mine was easier than yours because my outflow pipe went straight down to a floor drain ( concrete basement ). Also mine was just a slow drip leak . Because you need to turn your water off , it may be faster to call a plumber.

Comment: Thanks, I've asked elsewhere as well and the consensus is to call a plumber.